# ASC2EPH ASCII to Binary conversion

Tags: ascii, bin, fortran77

Trying to run an ASC2EPH.exe to convert linked ASCII DE405 files to binary JPLEPH file. Getting error when running in CMD - ASC2EPH<infile.405  (see [error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbXWU.jpg)). Any help appreciated.

Have run this on Simply Fortran and Force v3 both with same result. NRECL set to 1 for PC

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]. We do not know anything about the program you use. This is a coding site. If you are getting errors from.some code, you must show the source code.

Comment: Also, you will need the [tag:fortran] tag instead of the [tag:fortran77] tag. But first please rewrite the question to some acceptable form with the necessary details.